# Closing a Modal form through an event doesn't work

Tags: delphi

I have a `Modal` form that sends a request (with idTCpClient). Then inside an idTCPServer OnExecute event, that form should be closed (after receiving data).

The first `ShowModal;` and `Close;` executed as expected, but the second `close;` does not work and the form remains visible.

I have put a Button (`btnClose`) on the form to close it. If I use `btnClose.Click;` inside idTCPServer OnExecute event, the form doesn't get closed, but if I click on this button manually, the form is closed!

I execute this:

```
Procedure btnStart();
begin
  Form1.ShowModal;
end;
```

idTCPServer will execute this:

```
procedure idTCPServerOnExecute(...)
begin
  Form1.close //Or for testing purpose: Form1.btnClose.Click;  
end;
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the relevant parts of your code. Questions about the code you've written should include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It's hard to help you figure out what's wrong when you don't show us the code that isn't working.

Comment: -1. That is not your actual code, because `btnStart` would appear to be an event handler on a form, and can't exist without the form in the declaration, and `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` requires something other than a stand-alone procedure (it requires a method of an object, for a start). Please add an SSCCE, as I asked you previously. Posting made up nonsense is useless, and will not get you any help here. (In fact, it usually results in quick downvotes and closures, because if it's not worth your effort to produce an actual meaningful question, it's not worth ours to try and answer it.)

Comment: Thank you. I also expect that it's may be a thread issue(Because of idTCPServer). But how could I do this?

Comment: @Ken White thanks for your -1, I think the question itself is the point and don't need extra explains. But I will consider your comment in future questions.

Comment: The point is that when asking questions here about your code, you need to **actually post the code** that you're asking about, and I specifically asked you to do so. You chose instead to post made up, non-compiling nonsense. I rewarded your lack of effort with the appropriate response; a downvote for that lack of effort when you're asking us to spend our time helping you for free. ("Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.**") is a close reason here.

Comment: @Ken White - You right. I got the point. Thats "lack of effort" is just because I don't know the actual code and can't imagine it. Thank you

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Your question says "My code doesn't work", and now you're saying "I don't know the actual code and can't imagine it"? If you don't have any code, how can you tell that it's **not working**?  You've gone from not **posting** any code to not **having any code that doesn't work**? Well, I guess that's a new lack of effort I haven't seen before - "I have code that doesn't exist and that I can't even imagine, and it's not working. What's wrong?" is really something I've never seen here before.

Comment: No. It's just my language mistake(I am not a native english). I mean currently I don't have the actual code. Because I post the question from home and this problem is related to a work project. Excuse me for confusing.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense. "I'm not at my work computer right now, and that's where the code was written" would have been much more clear (although it would have been better in that case to wait until you got to work to post your question, so you **could** include the code - it's still hard to answer "My code doesn't work" questions without the actual code that isn't working.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Its `OnExecute` event runs in a worker thread and thus cannot safely access UI components.

For what you are attempting, the simplest solution is to use the `TIdNotify` class, eg:

```
Uses
  ..., IdSync;

procedure TSomeClass.IdTCPServerOnExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(Form1.Close);
  //Or for testing purpose:
  //TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(Form1.btnClose.Click);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked great. I'm confused. There is a `DataLog.Lines.Add(Buf);` that logs the received data and executed very well but form `close` does not work.

Comment: **Any** direct access to UI components from a worker thread is not safe.  Random things can happen. It **might** work by chance, but is more likely to cause crashes or deadlocks instead. So just do not do it at all. Any UI access needs to be synchronized with the main thread. The `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes do that, but there are other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1.ModalResult := mrOK;
```

ShowModal close form when the ModalResult get the value another than mrNone